# Merging datasets by id and maintain one row for each id

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to merge 2 datasets belonging to a single id with a larger dataset.

However, I am having trouble merging the two single row datasets into a single row within the larger dataset.

Is there a simple way to merge with dplyr and only overwrite values if they are NA's?

My data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:5, b=6:10, c=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), d=c(NA, 1,2,3, 4))
df2 <- data.frame(id=6, b=2, c="f", d=NA_real_)
df3 <- data.frame(id=6, b=NA_real_, c=NA_character_, d=5, e="a")

> df1
  id  b c  d
1  1  6 a NA
2  2  7 b  1
3  3  8 c  2
4  4  9 d  3
5  5 10 e  4
> df2
  id b c  d
1  6 2 f NA
> df3
  id  b    c d e
1  6 NA <NA> 5 a
```

My attempt:

```
merge1 <- dplyr::full_join(df1, df2) %>% full_join(df3)
```

Desired output:

```
output <- data.frame(id=1:6, b=c(6:10,2), c=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), d=c(NA, 1,2,3, 4, 5), e=c(NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, "a"))

> output
  id  b c  d    e
1  1  6 a NA <NA>
2  2  7 b  1 <NA>
3  3  8 c  2 <NA>
4  4  9 d  3 <NA>
5  5 10 e  4 <NA>
6  6  2 f  5    a
```

As opposed to:

```
  id  b    c  d    e
1  1  6    a NA <NA>
2  2  7    b  1 <NA>
3  3  8    c  2 <NA>
4  4  9    d  3 <NA>
5  5 10    e  4 <NA>
6  6  2    f NA <NA>
7  6 NA <NA>  5    a
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
list(df1, df2, df3) %>%
 bind_rows() %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 summarise_all(~ first(na.omit(.)))

     id     b c         d e    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <fct>
1     1     6 a        NA <NA> 
2     2     7 b         1 <NA> 
3     3     8 c         2 <NA> 
4     4     9 d         3 <NA> 
5     5    10 e         4 <NA> 
6     6     2 f         5 a
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
  bind_rows(mutate_if(df2, is.factor, as.character)) %>% 
  left_join(select(df3, id, d, e), by = "id") %>% 
  mutate(d= ifelse(is.na(d.x), d.y, d.x)) %>% 
  select(-d.x, -d.y)
```